# pwmconfig - no working fan sensors

Tags: fan, fancontrol

I'm currently setting up fan controls on my PC. When I run `pwmconfig` it says that I have no working fan sensors:

```
de@dust ~ $ sudo pwmconfig 
# pwmconfig revision 6166 (2013-05-01)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

Found the following devices:
   hwmon0 is acpitz
   hwmon1 is radeon
   hwmon2 is coretemp
   hwmon3 is asus

Found the following PWM controls:
   hwmon1/pwm1           current value: 71
hwmon1/pwm1 is currently setup for automatic speed control.
In general, automatic mode is preferred over manual mode, as
it is more efficient and it reacts faster. Are you sure that
you want to setup this output for manual control? (n) Y

Giving the fans some time to reach full speed...
Found the following fan sensors:
   hwmon3/fan1_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!

There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0.
Make sure you have a 3-wire fan connected.
You may also need to increase the fan divisors.
See doc/fan-divisors for more information.
```

I'm not sure why it thinks I have no working fan sensors, seeing as I have no problem using a fan controller in Windows..?

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error - There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0 while generating configuration file with pwmconfig,

Open first console and execute:

```
watch -n 1 "echo 2 > /sys/devices/platform/kernel_module/hwmon/hwmon[[:print:]]*/pwm1_enable"
```

If you use asus_fan kernel module and have 2nd fan, in second console:

```
 watch -n 1 "echo 2 > /sys/devices/platform/kernel_module/hwmon/hwmon[[:print:]]*/pwm2_enable"
```

And finally, in the third console:

```
sudo pwmconfig
```